# UNIQUE constraint failed on adding a new model field in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite, django-models

When i want to add a new field called *slug* to my *Post* model in **Djnago**, the migrate command will raise `UNIQUE constraint failed: new__chat_post.slug`

After that i remove that field from my model but the problem still exists. why?? and how to resolve this problem without deleting my whole table data??

The database is *sqlite3* and the *Django* version is 2.2 .

thanks.

The model:

```
class Post(models.Model):    
    title = models.TextField(max_length=100)
    context = models.TextField(max_length=255)
    creation_date  = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(default=["title"],unique=True)
```

Comment: Please post the code of the autogenerated migration so I can give you a more detailed answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because the migration generated by Django's `makemigrations` command is trying to set the default value `"title"` for every instance of the `Post` model that already exists in your database. But since the field is marked as `unique=True` this operation will fail.

In order to solve this you can manually modify the autogenerated migration so you prevent Django from trying to assign the same value to every instance and code your own logic to assign a unique value to the field `slug` of every pre-existing instance.

Comment: this is the migration code: 

`class Migration(migrations.Migration): dependencies = [ ('chat', '0012_post_slug'), ] operations = [ migrations.AlterField( model_name='post', name='slug', field=models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True), ), ]`

also the post titles is unique and differs from each other so the UNIQUE constrains shoud not be raise any error.
thanks for your answer but how to modify that action as you said???

Comment: this migration is only setting the `unique` constraint for the field, so the field must already be created therefore what is going on is that this migration is failing because you have non-unique values in the `slug` column. You need to make sure that the data in the `slug` column is unique prior to applying this migration. You can do that by using the django `shell` for example

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in multiple steps:

1. Add the "slug" field to your model, without the "unique=True" constraint.
2. Do "makemigrations" and "migrate".
3. Go into SQLite and use some SQL to set each "slug" field to a unique value e.g. like:

   `update app_post set slug=title;`
4. Add the "unique=True" constraint into your model.
5. Do another "makemigrations" and "migrate".

Done!

Explanation: at no point is the unique constraint violated (assuming your "title" field has unique values).